# Detect a dataChange while app is not running

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, agora.io

I am developing a social media app that has calling using the Agora SDK and so the way I detect if a user is being called is using Firebase RTDB and I wanted to ask if there was a way I can detect if a person is being called all while the app is closed so I can display the screen much like how Instagram, Whatsapp does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android ConnectionService to push notification when receiving a call. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService